# React native 57.7 black screen on ios

Tags: ios, react-native

we're trying to update our react native app from version 55 to 57.7. It's been really painfult but it's building both on ios & android. It's working fine on Android but on ios , it's stuck to a black screen. 
Looked like this issue, [Getting an entire black screen when running react-native run-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54430107/getting-an-entire-black-screen-when-running-react-native-run-ios). Did the same. no luck.
I even tried to simple view in the index.js, still black screen. there's no error in the developper console on neither js or xcode.
Not sure what I did wrong.

We followed the official procedure to upgrade fllowing the link: 
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

and my code lokks like this:
appDelegate.m

```
  #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
    #import <React/RCTPushNotificationManager.h>        
    #import <React/RCTRootView.h>
    #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
    #import <RNGoogleSignin/RNGoogleSignin.h>
    #import "Orientation.h"
    #import <ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h>

    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {

      NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

      #ifdef DEBUG
      jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
      #else
      jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
      #endif

      self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
      self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


      [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];
      [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                               didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
      return YES;
    }
```

index js

```
import {AppRegistry, View, Text} from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(APP_NAME, () => {
return(
 <View style={{ height:500, width:300, backgroundColor:"orange"}}>
  <Text>hello</Text>
</View>
);
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? I'm having the same problem upgrading from react native 0.58 to 0.59.